# Qiwi Payments /sinap/api/v2/terms/99/payments

Tags: python, aiohttp, qiwi

Не могу понять что не так с телом запроса. Приходит ответ 400.

````
qiwi = Qiwi(config.qiwi_token, config.qiwi_login, config.qiwi_secret)
    amount =  12.0
    account = "+79999999999"
    
    payment_id = get_unix(True)
    
    amount_str = str(amount)
    account_str = str(account)
    payment_id_str = str(payment_id)
    
    print(f"amount: {amount}")
    print(f"account: {account}")
    print(f"payment_id: {payment_id}")


    response = await qiwi.send_payment(payment_id_str, amount_str, account_str)
    print(f"response: {response}")``` 

В классе:

    ``` async def send_payment(self, payment_id, amount, account):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=self.session_headers,
                                         timeout=self.timeout) as session:

            url = "https://edge.qiwi.com/sinap/api/v2/terms/99/payments"
            
            #  JSON-объект с параметрами платежа
            payment_data = {
                "id": payment_id,
                "sum": {
                    "amount": amount,
                    "currency": "643"
                },
                "paymentMethod": {
                    "type": "Account",
                    "accountId": "643"
                },
                "comment": payment_id,
                "fields": {
                    "account": account
                }
            }
    
        
            headers = {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + self.token
            }
            
            # Отладочные сообщения
            print("URL:", url)
            print("Request Data:", payment_data)
        
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers, timeout=self.timeout) as session:
                response = await session.post(url, json=payment_data, timeout=self.timeout)
        
                #  статус HTTP-ответа
                print("HTTP Status:", response.status)
            
                if response.status == 200:
                    # Платеж успешно выполнен
                    response_data = await response.json()
                    # Отладочное сообщение для ответа
                    print("Response Data:", response_data)
                    return response_data
                else:
                    # Ошибка при выполнении платежа
                    print("Payment Error")
                    return None```
````